# ASP.NET 4.0 Deployment package include

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, msbuild, asp.net-4.0

The build Deployment package feature of Visual Studio 2010 doesn't copy the App_GlobalResources directory from my ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms application.

I know I can use for example "ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment" to exclude folders from the deployment, but how can I include this folder with MSBUILD?

Answer (score 0):

This: [Web Deployment Tool (MSDeploy) : Build Package including extra files or excluding specific files](http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx) might help.